# How do you upgrade NEAR smart contracts?

Tags: nearprotocol

If I've deployed a smart contract on NEAR, how do I upgrade it to a new version?  How can I tell if an existing smart contract can still be upgraded or has been frozen?

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the answer Erik already provided, I want to mention that even when there is no full-access keys on the account, the contract code can be re-deployed by the contract implementation itself (obviously, it should have a built-in support for that). You may also want to combine that with DAO to make the [upgrade process backed by a voting process](https://www.near-sdk.io/upgrading/via-dao-vote).

Comment: The link broke. I found https://github.com/near/sdk-docs/blob/main/docs/upgrading/via-dao-vote.md

Answer (score 1):

Upgrading is done with access keys.  If you want to be upgrading, you keep a full access key to the account, which allows you to deploy or delete/recreate/deploy.

Anyone can view the upgradeability of a contract (eg whether it can still be changed by the original owner) by viewing its keys to make sure that all full access keys have been removed using:

`NEAR_ENV=mainnet near keys contract_name.near`

Comment: why would the original owner want to remove the keys and loose access to the account containing the contract?

Comment: @PeterSalomonsen immutability of the code guaranties that nobody will ever change the initial behavior of the contract. Imagine you would allow the paper contract text being edited after the contract was signed by the parties.